# Spring Boot: Rollback transaction before request resolves

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, transactions

I've got a method in my service class which performs some changes to an entity, afterwards it executes some critical code (communication to different microservice) which may come back with error information attached to an exception. If an error occurs, the changes should be reverted. To achieve this I thought I'd use @Transactional.

#### Service

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository repository;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = CriticalCodeException.class, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
    public Entity foo(entity) {
        /* perform changes ... */
        entity.setBar(...) 
        try {
            /* critical code */
        } catch (CriticalCodeException e) {
            e.setEntityId(entity.getId());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public attachError(CriticalCodeException e) {
        // reload entity which should be rolled back but is not
        Entity reloaded = repository.findOne(e.getEntityId);
        reloaded.setError(e.getError); // attach error
        repository.save(reloaded)  // saves changes which should be rolled back
    }
}
```

As the CriticalCodeException is a RuntimeException and might also occur in another context, I've created a designated ExceptionHandler which is supposed to catch it and attach the error to my entity.

#### ExceptionHandler

```
@ExceptionHandler(CriticalCodeException .class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorResponse processError(CriticalCodeException e) {
    entityService.attachError(e);
    return e.getError();
}
```

Yet, when I attach the error I do not wont to save the pervious made changes too. So when I reload the entity after the Exception has been thrown out of my nested @Transactional-method I'd expect it to be in its initial state. Well, it is not. If I do not attach the error (and thus omit my save() call) the changes do not get persisted. So I figure the rollback eventually executes after my exception handling.

Can anybody tell me how I can access my entity in its initial state AFTER the rollback is done?

I am using Spring Boot Data with JPA and Hibernate. I've tried various configurations with things like @EnableTransactionManagement and setting up different combinations of beans. Yet, after a lot of research, I'm pretty confindent that the @Transactional is actually working (as to be seen from the eventual rollback described above) and should work without further configuration. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The changes were in fact rolled back but my entity-manager did not get reset, just M. Deinum pointed out. In my persistence setup changes to an entity were only persisted by a call to `repository.save(entity)`. What I did eventually was to omit the transactional approach and instead implement `repository.reload(entity)` which refreshes my entity via the entity-manager. This way I can get rid of previous made changes which did not even get persisted in the first place.

Comment: The fact that changes are rolled back (which they are) doesn't mean your entity gets reset!. If you want that you need to reload the data from the database. Also you probably are using an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` which attaches an `EntityManager` at the start of the request. As soon as your entity is attached to the `EntityManager` a call to `findOne` will always return that instance. You would need to clear the entity manager before doing a call to `findOne`.